# ko.toJSON does not pick up updated observable value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am stuck at collecting json data by ko.toJSON of knockout.js. There are several observable variables and I can collect some input fields when user typing some string but can not get button status when user clicking button.

html code:

```
<input type="text" name="port_name"
  class="form-control"
       data-bind="value: portName"
       placeholder="Enter name of port" />
<span class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-switch" 
          data-bind="css: btnStatus" 
          data-toggle="button"
          data-bind="aria-pressed: btnIsPressed"
          autocomplete="off">
    <i class="fa" data-bind="css: btnName"></i>
  </button>
</span>
```

If user write something in "port_name" field and click the button, then submit whole form, by using `ko.toJSON(viewmodel)` I can get json string in which portName is what user wrote but button status like "btnIsPressed" never get changed but just keep initial value. Also tried to add click function to force the value but it does not help...

```
$(function() //click funcion for Port Enable buttons
{
}).on('click', '.btn-switch', function(e) {
  if (this.getAttribute("aria-pressed") == true) {
    this.setAttribute("aria-pressed", false);
    console.log(this.getAttribute("aria-pressed"));
  } else {
    this.setAttribute("aria-pressed", false);
    console.log(this.getAttribute("aria-pressed"));
  }
});
```

From Console I can see "aria-pressed" value toggles but `ko.toJSON` result always initial value. Anything I missed? Thanks.

viewmodel as below:

```
//PortViewModel
function Port(_port_id, 
              _port_is_enabled,
              _max_number_of_ports_per_module,
              _id_of_last_port) {
    this.portId = ko.observable(_port_id); 
    var portStatus = _port_is_enabled;
    this.portName = ko.observable("No Name");//_port_name;

    this.btnStatus = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return (_port_is_enabled) ?
                "btn-success" : "active btn-danger";
    });

    this.btnIsPressed = ko.observable(_port_is_enabled);

    this.btnName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
        return (_port_is_enabled) ? "fa-play" : "fa-stop";
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show your model code as well.

Comment: Not just "btnIsPressed", other observables are not updated per user operation except for "portName".

Comment: Why do you have two separate `data-bind` for the button?  Do you have a custom binding for `aria-pressed` ?

Comment: btnStatus is for changing button style when user clicking it. "btnIsPressed" is the real trigger to tell server button get clicked.

Comment: I think you want to place both of those `data-bind` expressions into one string as described here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html

Comment: I tried to remove "btnIsPressed" data-bind and only leave "btnStatus", but still the same problem there.

Comment: It looks only part of bindings of  knockout.js are supporting 2-way binding. So need change viewmodel to fix this as discussed in another thread.  See this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374628/two-way-binding-on-attribute-knockout-js)

Comment: I feel like you are experiencing on focus out problem with value binding. Try to use textInput binding instead of value, like so:
<input type="text" name="port_name"
  class="form-control"
       data-bind="textInput: portName"
       placeholder="Enter name of port" />

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason, only part of bindings of  knockout.js are supporting 2-way binding. So need change viewmodel to fix this as discussed in another thread.  See this ([Two way binding on attribute, knockout.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22374628/two-way-binding-on-attribute-knockout-js))